# Uncluster Map Annotations

Tags: ios, mapkit

Before iOS 11 all of the pins that I put on my map were unclustered, but now even when zoomed all the way in all of my pins cluster automatically and it is degrading the user experience because the purpose of the app is to show fairly accurate locations. The clustering not only removes the accuracy but also hides many of the nearby pins.

Is there a way to remove the clustering? I found plenty of ways to cluster but nobody is talking about un-clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, creating a custom MKPointAnnotation and implementing

`mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

gets rid of the automatic point grouping. Hope this helps someone!